# Json.NET deserializing object returns null

Tags: c#, json, object, json.net

I would like to deserialize a string o JSON and output data on a string:

```
public class Test
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}

private void btnRetrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string json = @"{""Name"":{""id"":10,""name"":""Name"",""revisionDate"":1390293827000}}";
    var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);
    lblOutput.Text = output.name;
}
```

This is intended to output the `name` property of the string `json`. However, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JSON you posted can be deserialized into an object which has a `Name` propery of type `Test`, not into a `Test` instance.

This

```
string json = @"{""id"":10,""name"":""Name"",""revisionDate"":1390293827000}";
```

would be a representation of a `Test` instance.

Your JSON may be deserialized into something like this:

```
public class Test
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Test Name { get; set; }
}

// ...


var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
lblOutput.Text = output.Name.name;
```

Comment: Adding to this, it sometimes helps to drop your JSON into a visualizer tool to see these sorts of things jump out at you: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 0):

Valid json for Test class is below

{
    "Name": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Name",
        "revisionDate": 1390293827000
    }
}

and Also your json is in containg more data then only test class 
so you can also use like

```
Dictionary<string,Test> dictionary= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Test>>(json);

Test oputput=dictionary["Name"];
```